# missing Phoenix specific mix tasks / generators

Tags: elixir, generator, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

I'm missing Phoenix specific mix tasks, e.g. mix phoenix.gen.html

**$ mix help | grep -i phoenix**

mix local.phoenix     # Updates Phoenix locally

mix phoenix.new       # Creates a new Phoenix v1.2.1 application

**$ mix -v**

Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Mix 1.3.4

**$ elixir -v**

Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Elixir 1.3.4

I've re-installed Erlang, Node, Elixir, Phoenix on my Mac (using brew) and nothing seems to resolve the issue.

**Here is the output running it from the Phoenix app directory**

```
$ mix phoenix.new hello

$ cd hello

$ ls
README.md       brunch-config.js    deps            mix.exs            node_modules     priv            web _build          config          lib         mix.lock        package.json        test

$ mix -h | fgrep phoenix
mix local.phoenix     # Updates Phoenix locally
mix phoenix.new       # Creates a new Phoenix v1.2.1 application
```

Answer (score 10):

All tasks other than `local.phoenix` and `phoenix.new`, like `phoenix.gen.html` are only available from inside a Phoenix app's diretory. You should see them in `mix help` if you run it from inside an app's directory.

Note: You'll have to compile the app once using `mix compile` if you want to see it appear in `mix help` in a brand new app that has never been compiled. If you directly to run one of those task though, it will succeed since `mix` will compile the app before trying to run it.

Outside any app's directory:

```
$ mix help | grep phoenix
mix local.phoenix     # Updates Phoenix locally
mix phoenix.new       # Creates a new Phoenix v1.2.1 application
```

Inside an app's directory (make sure the app is compiled by running `mix compile` first):

```
$ mix help | grep phoenix
mix local.phoenix        # Updates Phoenix locally
mix phoenix.digest       # Digests and compress static files
mix phoenix.gen.channel  # Generates a Phoenix channel
mix phoenix.gen.html     # Generates controller, model and views for an HTML based resource
mix phoenix.gen.json     # Generates a controller and model for a JSON based resource
mix phoenix.gen.model    # Generates an Ecto model
mix phoenix.gen.presence # Generates a Presence tracker
mix phoenix.gen.secret   # Generates a secret
mix phoenix.new          # Creates a new Phoenix v1.2.1 application
mix phoenix.routes       # Prints all routes
mix phoenix.server       # Starts applications and their servers
```

Comment: $ mix phoenix.new hello
* creating hello/config/config.exs
...
cd hello
$ ls
README.md  brunch-config.js deps   mix.exs   node_modules  priv   web
_build   config   lib   mix.lock  package.json  test
$ mix -h | fgrep phoenix
mix local.phoenix     # Updates Phoenix locally
mix phoenix.new       # Creates a new Phoenix v1.2.1 application

Comment: @user7017138 you'll have to compile the app first. Please see my edit.

Comment: Thank you Dogbert!! Compiling was the missing step.